# Open new window with a clean localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So we are using localstorage in out webapp so that you are "logged in" when you return to the app. The issue is sometimes in our admin area we open up peoples 'cart' pages which logs us in, normally before we close the page we logout and then close so that when we open the app for ourselves later we're not logged in as the user we opened up before.

Is there a way to open a window with a clear localstorage and have it not save the localstorage so that when the window is closed it doesn't save the localstorage over to the other windows? My first thought was to see if I can open a private window but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: is `sessionService` what you are looking for?

Comment: i don't think there is a way to open a window without localStorage.
But i could not understand what is the problem exactly. You are saying if you are logged in unless you signout you will logged in automatically if u come back again. Admin is also logged in then what is the problem. Can you please explain.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald `sessionService` would be okay in the case that it's opened from the admin, but in the case where it's not, meaning it's probably an end user, then `sessionService` will throw out the login info when they close and we don't want that. But that may be the way we need to go to just somehow determine where it's being opened from.

Comment: @rajesh the scenario is we open the users cart in the app to see that all their items are there and we can even charge their card there if they are having problems. When we close this, since it's saved in `localstorage` when we open up the app again we're still logged in as them and any previous user was logged out. So I'm trying to get a way to open our app like that without tramping on the previous user and being still logged in after closing.

Comment: i guess you should store some unique id in localStorage when user actually logs in which is related to that perticualr user. You should not change this local Storage value when you just browse as the user. And it should get removed only when you logout. Hope i understood ur problem.

Comment: It seems we'll have to use a combination of session storage along with passing some sort of value so the app knows to get it's info from session rather than local storage.

Comment: You can create a small script that basically renames the local storage variables for that user, so just fire that before switching to a new window and click a second button to rename it back when you close it. But it's a little horrific :)